# joda PeriodFormatter prints null

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I must be missing something.

```
private PeriodFormatter fmt = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .printZeroNever()
            .appendHours()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendMinutes()
            .appendSeparator(":")
            .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
            .appendSeconds()
            .toFormatter();
```

and then

```
Period period = new Period(DateTime.now().getMillis()-startDate.getMillis(), PeriodType.millis());

Log.i("date", "fmt.print(period): " + fmt.print(period));
Log.i("date", "period.toString() : " + period.toString());
Log.i("date", "DateTime.now().getMillis()-startDate.getMillis() : " + (DateTime.now().getMillis()-startDate.getMillis()));
```

my logs are

```
fmt.print(period): 
period.toString() : PT12.166S
DateTime.now().getMillis()-startDate.getMillis() : 12166
```

Thanks

---EDIT

ok found it, the problem was that by specifiying " PeriodType.millis()" in the period constructor I got period this way : 0min 0 seconds 152150 ms
I don't know if I'm clear but that was my mistake, I removed this argument and now it works like a charm.

```
Period period = new Period(startDate.getMillis(), DateTime.now().getMillis());
```

Comment: what do you want to get at result?

Comment: Sorry I want "2:55" for 2 minuts 55 seconds, "1:05:01" for 1h 5min 1s

Answer (score 0):

The [Period](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class has the following Contructor:

```
Period(long startInstant, long endInstant, PeriodType type)
```

Try Changing:

```
     Period period = new Period(DateTime.now().getMillis()-startDate.getMillis(), PeriodType.millis());
```

to:

```
  Period period = new Period(DateTime.now().getMillis(), startDate.getMillis(), PeriodType.millis());
```

Comment: it's the same result, you're right thought I'll do it this way

Answer (score 0):

It is rather strange behavior that it is printing out an empty string, but it is because you are asking it to print out for type milliseconds, but you did not include .appendMillis() in your formatter definition.

It should be something like:

```
private PeriodFormatter fmt = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
        .printZeroAlways()
        .appendHours()
        .appendSeparator(":")
        .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
        .appendMinutes()
        .appendSeparator(":")
        .minimumPrintedDigits(2)
        .appendSeconds()
        .appendSeparator(".")
        .appendMillis()
        .toFormatter();
```

Comment: I don't want to print millis, My question have been edited with the answer yesterday. Thanks for the help thought

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that by specifiying " PeriodType.millis()" in the period constructor I got period this way : 0min 0 seconds 152150 ms I don't know if I'm clear but that was my mistake, I removed this argument and now it works like a charm.

```
Period period = new Period(startDate.getMillis(),DateTime.now().getMillis());
```